# Do I have to switch to https to use "SharedArrayBuffer" in Chrome 92?

Tags: javascript, http, https

My website does not work with Chrome 92.  With Chrome 91 everything was fine. The problem is that `SharedArrayBuffer` is not enabled since Chrome 92. When I try to enable it by adding the header "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: requre-corp and Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin" I get the error message:

> The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead. See https://www.w3.org/TR/powerful-features/#potentially-trustworthy-origin and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-cross-origin-opener-policy-header.

Does "Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol" mean I have to switch to HTTPS only to use `SharedArrayBuffer`?  If so, what’s the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to use HTTPS.

Certain features (which includes SharedArrayBuffer, due to the revelations of Spectre-style attacks) are security-sensitive and require a greater degree of isolation. COOP/COEP allows the browser to isolate your page from other sites to a greater degree, which allows this feature to be safer to use.

Some features, including COOP, have significant effects on how the browser treats content from your origin. The browser can't be sure that this assertion hasn't been tampered with unless it is delivered from a potentially trustworthy origin (if that's not localhost, this means over HTTPS).

Comment: Can you please explain why HTTPS is needed? Maybe with an example.

Comment: The explanation is in there: _The browser can't be sure that this assertion hasn't been tampered with..._. And browsers are getting stricter and stricter with the allowed activity if they can't be sure whom they're talking about