# SharedArrayBuffer is NOT supported in your browser

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, cornerstone, orthanc-server

I'm using cornerstone which sends a request to a reverse proxy that redirect the request to the an orthanc server for CORS blocks, and all of this using http because I can't use https

I see this question related with the same problem which solution is to change to https.
[Do I have to switch to https to use "SharedArrayBuffer" in Chrome 92?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68567653/do-i-have-to-switch-to-https-to-use-sharedarraybuffer-in-chrome-92)

here https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/ tolds that I can do this in the webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
hot: true,
open: false,
port: 3333,
historyApiFallback: true,
allowedHosts:"all",
headers: {

 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
 "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
 "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",

}
```

But the result is both

The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead. See https://www.w3.org/TR/powerful-features/#potentially-trustworthy-origin and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-cross-origin-opener-policy-header.

And

createFloat32SharedArray.ts:35 Uncaught (in promise) Error: SharedArrayBuffer is NOT supported in your browser see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/

So i have to delete "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
"Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",

And add "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": " none" in order to avoid de CORS, but still getting the sharedBuffedArray error.

I also try enable the Experimental JavaScript shared memory features flag in my chrome browser but I'm still getting the sharedBufferedArray error

Experimental JavaScript shared memory features
Enable web pages to use non-standard, experimental JavaScript shared memory features. Their use requires the same HTTP headers required by cross-thread usage of SharedArrayBuffers (i.e. COOP and COEP). – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Android, Fuchsia, Lacros

#enable-javascript-experimental-shared-memory

And finally I tried an older version of google chrome but then I get StructureClone error because is not yet implemented in those versions.

Is there a way to solve this problem while using http?